# Linking iPhone app with OpenCycleMap?

Tags: ios, openstreetmap

I’m currently working on an iPhone application that shows visitors where to walk in my local town.  Using GPS on the http://www.opencyclemap.org/  map I want the user to be able to see where they are on the trail.  Just like the beeping dot when you use google or apple maps.

What I don’t know is how do I get my app to interface with opencyclemap so that the user can see where they are with the GPS.  What would be the easiest or most appropriate way to achieve this.  I don’t mind if the user is directed out of my app to the open cycle map page.  If they could stay within the app this would be good.

I understand this is a high level question and as such expect a fair amount of questions to drill into specifics.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCyleMap is a set of map tiles made from OpenStreetMap data. You just need to create a mapping application showing a user's location, with those tiles as a basemap. The URL for the tilelayer is `http://{s}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, with `a` and `b` subdomains (e.g. http://b.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/1/1/1.png, which ends up in the ocean).

Comment: Thankyou!   This looks like it would take the end user to the designated map tile.   What I don't understand is how does the application know that it needs to implement a GPS marking representing the end users location (as opposed to just seeing a map)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything at all about developing an iOS application, and that is better asked somewhere like StackOverflow. Presumably it's possible to make an application that checks a user's location, and displays that as a point over map tiles. There are lots of apps that do this already, such as bus trackers.

Comment: Note that OpenCycleMap is a service provided by Thunderforest, and if your app becomes popular you may need to sign up for a service plan - see http://thunderforest.com/terms/ .